# RootViewController to TabBarViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.5

What is the way to use multiple buttons on root view controller linked with different tab views in Xcode 4.5?

I have got 4 buttons on the home screen, I want the flow goes as when I tap on a button1 it should go to tab1 similarly when I tap on button2 tab2 should be open.

What should I do?

Dummy Code Ignore this.

```
{
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create 4 viewControllers and append below code in  app delegates method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like bellow..

First Create object of `UITabBarController` in `AppDelegate` class and alloc in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method like bellow..

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController2 = [[[UITabBarController alloc]init]autorelease];
self.tabBarController3 = [[[UITabBarController alloc]init]autorelease];
```

After create method for set Different Tab as a RootViewController like bellow...

```
-(void)setRootViewControllerTab1{

    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    UINavigationController *navviewController1 , *navviewController2,;

    viewController1 = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navviewController1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    navviewController1.title = @"Title1";


    viewController2 = [[[HowItWorksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navviewController2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    navviewController2.title = @"Title2";
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navviewController1, navviewController2, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
-(void)setRootViewControllerTab2{

    UIViewController *viewController3, *viewController4;
    UINavigationController *navviewController3 , *navviewController4;
    /////TAB 2/////***********
    viewController3 = [[[CUHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController3" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navviewController3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    navviewController3.title = @"Title3";

    viewController4 = [[[CUFavouritiesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController4" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navviewController4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
    navviewController4.title = @"Title4";
    self.tabBarController2.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navviewController3, navviewController4, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController2;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Call above method with `AppDelegate` object like bellow...

**For Example:** button1 clicked at that time in method write this code...

```
- (IBAction)btn1_Clicked:(id)sender{
        AppDelegate *objApp = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [objApp setRootViewControllerTab1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
 UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease]; self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4]; 
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
```

Create a tabbar controller like this

Call above method with AppDelegate object like bellow...

For Example: button1 clicked at that time in method write this code...

```
- (IBAction)btn1_Clicked:(id)sender{
    AppDelegate *objApp = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    objApp.tabbarcontroller.selectedindex = 2;
}
```

you can change selectedIndex